# How do you determine if a spell can damage objects?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, saving-throw

In chat I learned that [failing a saving throw against a spell can potentially damage worn equipment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Saving-Throw): "If a creature rolls a natural 1 on its saving throw against the effect, however, an exposed item is harmed (if the attack can harm objects)."

But how does one determine if a spell can damage objects?

#### Examples

- The spell [*shatter*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shatter) has *(object)* in its [saving throw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Saving-Throw) entry, so it can be cast on objects and, therefore, damage objects.
- The spell [*fireball*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) says it damages objects.
- The spell [*cone of cold*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cone-of-cold) does *not* say it damages objects, but it *is* an area spell that deals energy damage (i.e. acid, electricity, fire, sonic, and, in this case, cold) and, as such, has [specific rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects).
- The spell [*flame strike*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flame-strike) does *not* say it damages objects, *and* it, too, is an area spell that deals energy damage, but also half the spell's damage is divine rather than energy.
- The spell [*chaos hammer*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chaos-hammer) is described as "a multicolored explosion of leaping, ricocheting energy," but it does *not* technically deal energy damage.
- The spell [*slay living*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slay-living) has as its target *living creature touched* so it shouldn't damage objects.

Related question include [Do area of effect spells damage objects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86511/23196) (about *3.5e*'s *cone of cold*), [Kill with magic = destroy carried items?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89021/23196) (about worn items damaged by spells without saving throw), and [Did my clothes catch fire?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49964/8610) (about damaging clothing), but none address this issue specifically with *Pathfinder* in mind.

Comment: If it helps, consider a living target wearing a variety of magical and non-magical gear, next to 2 scarecrows, each identical to the living target, except one made of straw and the other made of metal.

Comment: The related question "Do area of effect spells damage objects?" is tagged dnd-3.5e. This question is tagged pathfinder. The answers to that question might not be relevant for this one.

Comment: @Snappie PF and 3.5e are very similar, and while the cited rule is slightly different for PF (I linked the PF version in the question), the discussion is still related. Although if it interferes with you ability to answer the question, feel free to ignore that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this GM's opinion, a spell's description provides the only guidance for determining if a spell that has an *Area* entry that also deals damage *also* deals that damage to objects within that area.

That is, while [Damaging Objects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects) on [Saving Throws](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Saving-Throws) on Attended Items *does* say, "Unless the descriptive text for a spell (or attack) specifies otherwise, all items carried or worn by a creature are assumed to survive a magical attack," on Unattended Items says, "Non-magical, unattended items never make saving throws. They are considered to have failed their saving throws, so they are always fully affected by spells and other attacks that allow saving throws to resist or negate," *but* when taken together it's unclear if this means **either** *All items not carried or worn by a creature are assumed to be dealt damage by effects that affect an area* **or** *A spell (or attack) will specify that items not carried or worn by a creature are dealt damage by effects that affect an area*.

While this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/93788/8610) gravitates toward *All items not carried or worn by a creature are assumed to be dealt damage by effects that affect an area*, in this GM's campaigns *A spell (or attack) will specify that items not carried or worn by a creature are dealt damage by effects that affect an area.* A reader may judge me lazy, but I just don't want to track damage to unattended objects (and have that matter) if I don't have to. I feel there are better ways for a GM to spend his time. To that end, to determine if a spell deals damage to unattended objects in its area, I use as a guideline a *really strict* reading of those 40-year-old standbys, the spells [*fireball*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) and [*lightning bolt*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lightning-bolt).

Bear with me here. The spell [*fireball*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) says that

> A *fireball* spell generates a searing explosion of flame that detonates with a low roar and deals 1d6 points of fire damage per caster level (maximum 10d6) to every creature within the area. **Unattended objects also take this damage**.… **The *fireball*** sets fire to combustibles and **damages objects in the area**. It can melt metals with low melting points, such as lead, gold, copper, silver, and bronze. **If the damage caused to an interposing barrier shatters or breaks through it, the *fireball* may continue beyond the barrier if the area permits; otherwise it stops at the barrier just as any other spell effect does.**

(Emphasis mine.) Similarly, the spell [*lightning bolt*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lightning-bolt) says

> **The *lightning bolt*** sets fire to combustibles and **damages objects in its path.** It can melt metals with a low melting point, such as lead, gold, copper, silver, or bronze. **If the damage caused to an interposing barrier shatters or breaks through it, the *bolt* may continue beyond the barrier if the spell's range permits; otherwise, it stops at the barrier just as any other spell effect does.**

(Emphasis mine.) Some will be quick to point out that just because, for example, the (equally elderly) spell [*flame strike*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flame-strike) does not *say* it deals damage to unattended objects in its cylinder also does *not* mean it *doesn't* deal damage to unattended objects object in its cylinder. But, because—unlike *fireball* and *lightning bolt*—there are no *specific* rules for what happens to a barrier when part of a *flame strike*'s effect intersects with it, *this* GM has the *flame strike* spell stop at the barrier [just as any other spell effect does](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) *and* leave the barrier undamaged. That's just how I roll. (As the spell *flame strike* has as its area a cylinder, its effect usually ignores obstructions, but this GM would *not* let a *flame strike* spell ignore, for example, a [*wall of stone*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-stone) spell that'd been cast to form a dome *above* creatures in the *flame strike*'s area!)

This ruling *does* lessen the danger of the [natural-1-on-a-saving-throw-and-see-an-item-damaged](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Saving-Throws) rule, but this GM is comfortable with that, viewing that particular rule as a throwback to the hoary days of insult-to-injury *Gotcha!* DMing anyway.

That said, in my campaigns here's how the examples work.

- The spell [***shatter***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shatter), when it's used—as described in its second paragraph—as an area spell

  > destroys non-magical objects of crystal, glass, ceramic, or porcelain. All such unattended objects within a 5-foot radius of the point of origin are smashed into dozens of pieces by the spell. Objects weighing more than 1 pound per your level are not affected, but all other objects of the appropriate composition are shattered.

  However, according to the spell's second saving throw entry, a creature in the area that's *attending* objects that such a *shatter* could affect makes a Will save to negate the spell's effect. Yet all of a creature's attended items are affected if the creature *either* fails the Will saving throw *or* rolls a natural 1 on the Will saving throw, so, ultimately, it doesn't matter, the results of either being identical. (This GM would have an appropriate magic item possessing a higher Will saving throw bonus than the attending creature make its Will saving throw separately. Then this GM would chide that creature for have a weaker will than its magic items.)
- The aforementioned spell [***fireball***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) says specifically that it damages objects. Thus the spell *fireball* damages unattended objects within its area, and a creature that rolls a natural 1 on its Relfex saving throw against the spell will find that one of its attended magic items has suffered fire damaged.
- The spells [***cone of cold***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cone-of-cold) and the aforementioned [***flame strike***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flame-strike) do not say they damage objects. Thus the spells *cone of cold* and *flame strike* leave their surroundings untouched, and a creature that rolls a natural 1 on its Reflex saving throw against either spell will find its attended magic items undamaged.
- The spell [***chaos hammer***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chaos-hammer) describes its damage as being dealt first to "lawful and neutral (not chaotic) creatures" then to "creatures who are neither lawful nor chaotic," yet the spell is silent on objects. Thus the spell *chaos hammer*—although its effect's described as a "multicolored explosion of leaping, ricocheting energy"—leaves its surroundings untouched, and a creature that rolls a natural 1 on its Will saving throw against the spell will find its attended magic items undamaged.
- The spell [***slay living***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/slay-living) requires the caster to "succeed on a melee touch attack to touch the target," and that target must be a living creature. The spell *slay living* doesn't affect an area (so its surroundings are (*ahem*) untouched), and it *can't* damage objects, so a creature's natural 1 on the spell's Fortitude saving throw doesn't *slay* one of its attended magic items.

I should note that the alternative gets messy. For example, not only will a warrior find his [tower shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/shield-tower) (that most portable of barriers—no matter how [ill-advised](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48494/8610)) dissolving under assaults that would've previously left it unharmed (having, after all, only [hardness 5 and hp 20](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects)), but also remember that areas are usually *solids* not *planes*, even though they are often represented as planes for convenient grid placement. That means casters must become *extremely* cautious or find their spells destroying the very structures on which they're fighting, and dragons must be wary lest their breath weapons collapse their own lairs! That is, the alternative would see every 5-ft. square of terrain in an area dealt damage, and that damage may destroy the very adventure site, not to mention, inadvertently, the party!

So that's *this* GM's standard for whether or not a spell affects objects, unattended or not *and* area spell or not. I'm not, like, *utterly inflexible* on this, though. For example, because a [ray](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) is like "using a ranged weapon," such a spell could be directed at anything (including objects or the darkness), and the spell'll affect objects appropriately (e.g. the spells [*scorching ray*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scorching-ray) and [*polar ray*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polar-ray) as [ranged](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Ranged-Weapon-Damage) [energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Energy-Attacks) attacks deal [one-fourth](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/83190/8610) or [one-third](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Multiplying) damage to objects, but most objects will be unaffected by the spell [*ray of enfeeblement*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/ray-of-enfeeblement)). However, a caster that wants, for example, a spell like *cone of cold* except that it also damages objects in the area like *fireball* (only, y'know, in a *cone* and with *cold*) would have to [research and design](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Research-and-Designing-Spells) that spell.

Answer (score 3):

[Energy Attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Energy-Attacks) deal half damage to most objects. Most items get [saving throws](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Saving-Throws). In fact, there is a table available to you in the event of magical attacks.

The [damaging objects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects) section is pretty straight forward.

There is very little reason to believe any spell that deals damage *should not have the ability* to deal damage to objects; unless the spell description states *otherwise*.

Comment: One of *my* little reasons to believe otherwise is that *fireball*, for example, says, "If the damage caused to an interposing barrier shatters or breaks through it, the *fireball* may continue beyond the barrier if the area permits; otherwise it stops at the barrier *just as any other spell effect does*" (emphasis mine). Without other similar spells saying likewise, it's unclear how the DM is to manage effects as this answer describes.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Fireball would deal damage to said barrier. If it deals enough damage to destroy the barrier, it can continue to damage other things. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: Let me expand: Unlike *fireball*, the spell *chaos hammer*, for example,  says nothing about damaging barriers (which are, typically, objects). This answer seems to imply the DM should run *chaos hammer* as damaging barriers like *fireball* damages barriers despite *chaos hammer* not mentioning *anything* about damaging barriers. *But* the *chaos hammer* effect, in *fireball*'s words,  seems like it should operate "just as any other spell effect does" and *stop* at barriers instead of damaging them. How does the DM fairly adjudicate the effect of a spell like *chaos hammer*?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Simple... The spell description says "Only creatures are harmed by this spell." It couldn't penetrate an object barrier, such as hiding behind a wall.

Comment: An imperfect example, then. Replace with *cone of cold.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan "Energy attacks deal half damage to most objects." The object could possibly cause line of effect issues. From Fireball's text: "otherwise it stops at the barrier just as any other spell effect does." Cone of Cold would be any other spell in that regard, despite doing damage to the barrier. Fireball, with it's special mention, is unique.

Comment: So this answer's saying that any other appropriate spell effect also stops at *and damages* the barrier, yet *fireball*, uniquely, stops at the barrier and damages the barrier, *but also* if its damage destroys the barrier, it continues on? Is that accurate?

Comment: @HeyICanChan All I can really say, Fireball has unique text in regards to barriers. Cone of Cold does not. If a GM wants to use Fireball as a precedent for other AoE spells, that's his game, not mine.

Comment: The question asks about *cone of cold* and similar spells. If the answer is, ultimately, that the rules are unclear and that it's a GM's call as to whether *cone of cold* and similar spells damage objects, then that a reasonable GM can make that call *is* a reason to believe such spells do *not* have the ability to deal damage to objects unless they say so specifically. (I'm not trying to give you a hard time. I'm only hesitant about the answer's conclusions because, for example, I don't want to worry about a dragon's breath weapon destroying its own lair!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan How can I edit this answer to be more satisfactory? Also... I think dragons probably use their breath weapon to help shape their lairs. I have absolutely nothing to base that assumption on, but... why not?

Comment: Take a more nuanced stance. "There is very little reason to believe any spell that deals damage should not have the ability to deal damage to objects" implies those who disagree aren't as good at this as you. But, there is, in fact, a decent reason to believe otherwise, and that's that spells only do what they say they do, and if they don't say they damage objects (like *fireball* does), then they don't. Of, if you'd rather this answer dispel that concern *instead* of taking a gentler, nuanced stance, that's cool, too.